# Xcode with SVN can't commit files

Tags: xcode, svn

I have a project with SVN source control.

There are 2 files that when I commit appears with `U M` and I can't commit at all. The files are not selectable.

[image]

How can I risolve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue today.
Just because the file is not the latest version.
All I need to do is update the file first and then modify, commit again.

Comment: Why don't you think I meet the same question?
I also saw files with U M characters... and could not be selected to commit in XCode.